# Functional coverage report from FCOVER of Riviera-PRO EDU 2014.10 tool from ALDEC

Tags: system-verilog, function-coverage

The following is a functional coverage report(cov.txt) generated using Riviera-PRO EDU 2014.10 tool under EDA Playground based on the following commands as applied in http://www.edaplayground.com/x/96S

vsim +access+r;
run -all;
acdb save
acdb report -db fcover.acdb -txt -o cov.txt;

Kindly suggest any documentation to analyse the coverage figure computation based on the defined cover groups and cover points.

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++  REPORT INFO  ++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


=================================================
| User               | runner                   |
| Host               | eb37055383a7             |
|--------------------|--------------------------|
| Tool               | Riviera-PRO 2014.10      |
|--------------------|--------------------------|
| Report file        | /home/runner/cov.txt     |
| Report date        | 2014-12-08 06:47         |
| Report arguments   |                          |
|--------------------|--------------------------|
| Input file         | /home/runner/fcover.acdb |
| Input file date    | 2014-12-08 06:47         |
|--------------------|--------------------------|
| Test name (status) | fcover (Ok)              |
=================================================


++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++          HIERARCHY         ++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


CUMULATIVE SUMMARY
=====================================================
| Coverage type       | Weight |     Hits/Total     |
=====================================================
| Covergroup Coverage |      1 | 29.861% / 100.000% |
|---------------------|--------|--------------------|
| Types               |        |              0 / 2 |
=====================================================
CUMULATIVE INSTANCE-BASED COVERAGE: 29.861%
FILES: 2 COVERED INSTANCES: 0 / 1


INSTANCE - /alutest : work.alutest


    SUMMARY
    ============================================================================
    | Coverage type       | Weight |  Local Hits/Total  | Recursive Hits/Total |
    ============================================================================
    | Covergroup Coverage |      1 | 29.861% / 100.000% |   29.861% / 100.000% |
    |---------------------|--------|--------------------|----------------------|
    | Types               |        |              0 / 2 |                0 / 2 |
    ============================================================================
    WEIGHTED AVERAGE LOCAL:  29.861%
    WEIGHTED AVERAGE RECURSIVE:  29.861%


    COVERGROUP COVERAGE
    ======================================================================
    | Covergroup                        |  Hits   |  Goal /  | Status    |
    |                                   |         | At Least |           |
    ======================================================================
    | TYPE alutest.op_cov               |  6.250% | 100.000% | Uncovered |
    ======================================================================
    | TYPE alutest.zeros_or_ones_on_ops | 53.472% | 100.000% | Uncovered |
    ======================================================================


++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++        DESIGN UNITS        ++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


CUMULATIVE SUMMARY
=====================================================
| Coverage type       | Weight |     Hits/Total     |
=====================================================
| Covergroup Coverage |      1 | 29.861% / 100.000% |
|---------------------|--------|--------------------|
| Types               |        |              0 / 2 |
=====================================================
CUMULATIVE DESIGN-BASED COVERAGE: 29.861%
FILES: 2 COVERED DESIGN UNITS: 0 / 1


MODULE - work.alutest


    SUMMARY
    =====================================================
    | Coverage type       | Weight |     Hits/Total     |
    =====================================================
    | Covergroup Coverage |      1 | 29.861% / 100.000% |
    |---------------------|--------|--------------------|
    | Types               |        |              0 / 2 |
    =====================================================
    WEIGHTED AVERAGE:  29.861%


    COVERGROUP COVERAGE
    ======================================================================
    | Covergroup                        |  Hits   |  Goal /  | Status    |
    |                                   |         | At Least |           |
    ======================================================================
    | TYPE alutest.op_cov               |  6.250% | 100.000% | Uncovered |
    ======================================================================
    | TYPE alutest.zeros_or_ones_on_ops | 53.472% | 100.000% | Uncovered |
    ======================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

The [IEEE 1800-2012 SystemVerilog LRM](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) describes how to specify covergroups and coverpoints. See **Section 19. Function coverage**.

For overview, doing a [Google search on Functional Coverage](https://www.google.com/search?q=functional%20coverage) brings up a lot of resources.

If you have more specific questions, please ask a new StackOverflow question.